# Java HashMap Object, Integer

Tags: java, class, integer, hashmap

I have the following map:

```
Map<City, Integer> map = getMap();
```

and my class City:

```
public class City {
    private String c1;
    private String c2;

    public City(String c1, String c2){
        this.c1 = c1;
        this.c2 = c2;
    }
```

Now I have a map full of values, and I need to look for a specific key, for example :"London, Paris". My main approach is this one:

```
map.get(new City("London", "Paris"));
```

For some reason, it is giving me

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

and I'm almost sure I cannot do this way.

Comment: Can you post the whole stack trace? And have you debugged to verify that map isn't null at that point?

Answer (score 2):

Implement the `hashCode` and `equals` methods for the `City` class, otherwise `map.get(new City("London", "Paris"));` will always return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting the nullpointer when you try to use the result. For this to work you also need to implement the equals and hashcode methods of city.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `hashCode` and `equals`, if you are going to use your class in a hash map:

```
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((c1 == null) ? 0 : c1.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((c2 == null) ? 0 : c2.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
```

The implementation of equals should be trivial.

Your code fails because you do not define for the compiler how to compare two City objects. You can define comparison rules by overriding the `equals` function. Whenever you override the equals function, you should also override the `hashCode` function. The `hashCode` function is used by a hash map to store key-value pairs in a meaningful and optimal way. The `hashCode` function is also used when performing a look-up in a hash map.

You can find more copious and more accurate information on these semantics in the following article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There're a couple of reasons as to why you might experience a NullPointerException:

- Your map is null. So when you do a `map.get()` it throws you the exception
- Since you've not overriden the `equals()` and `hashCode()` method, when you do a `get()`, the map doesn't return you the correct object, it returns a null instead. When you try to work with this, well, you get the exception.